# Javascript - get button data attribute value, push into array and calculate

Tags: javascript

Lurker and new to posting here.

I'm looking for a solution to this:

```
<a points="0" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a points="1" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a points="2" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>

<div class="success"></div>
<div class="failure"></div>
```

I need to find a way for a function/loop, to add the data attribute value (points) into an array, and calculate that if the result is >3 to show the "success" div, else to hide it and show the "failure" div.

I've no idea where to start honestly here and would appreciate help. I searched online for some results to put some code together but there wasn't too much on grabbing data attribute value on click and pushing it into an array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm, googling "how to get html attribute value on click with javascript" gave me nearly 5 million results... That's some very basic stuff here

Comment: Also use `data-points` to adhere to standard. `points` is not a standard attribute

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+data-attributes+hide+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also on what event do you add? Why do you need to add if you already know the number on the server?

Comment: Lastly look at classList.toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments:

- use data-points to adhere to standard. points is not a standard attribute
- Also on what event do you add? Why do you need to add if you already know the number on the server? –
- Lastly look at classList.toggle:

```js
let result = [];
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("btn")) {
    result.push(+tgt.dataset.points)
  }
  if (tgt.id === "last") {
    const sum = result.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    document.querySelector('.success').classList.toggle('hide', sum < 3)
    document.querySelector('.failure').classList.toggle('hide', sum >= 3)
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a data-points="0" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="1" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="2" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="3" href="#" id="last" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<div class="success hide">Success</div>
<div class="failure hide">Failure</div>
```

Old answer:

```js
let sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('a[data-points]')]
  .map(anchor => +anchor.dataset.points)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)

document.querySelector('.success').classList.toggle('hide', sum < 3)
document.querySelector('.failure').classList.toggle('hide', sum >= 3)
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a data-points="0" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="1" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="2" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="3" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<div class="success">Success</div>
<div class="failure">Failure</div>
```

Comment: just an awesome solution. Same `map`, `reduce` i was thinking of using

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the code!

The event is on click of the button (all these buttons have the same class) it would push the data attribute value into the array and calculate. So some kind of loop to keep calculating I guess.

Comment: @DanielN If you do not know, then how can we know ;)
What is the usecase and what is the expected result when the user does what?

Comment: @mplungjan I thought I wrote it in the main post, my bad. Basically it's part of a multistep-form/slider where there are end results (success or failure) and each of those buttons has a numerical data value. The event occurs on each button click (so if a user clicks on the button with 0 value on the first slide, then 1, then 1 again they would be shown failure because it's under 3) So if a user selects the lower ones they get the failure div, if not the success div. We assign numerical values to them to be easier to manage as a sort of point system.

Comment: Where does the array come into play? It is really very hard to visualise your setup without a [mcve]

Comment: It's basically like this example (https://www.giosg.com/hubfs/Blogs%202020-2021/Single%20vs%20Multistep%20Form/0621-blog-single_vs_multistep-form.webp).
So the user get's introduced into a multi-step form, they're offered 4 slides with 4 options inside of each. Each answer holds a value from 0 to 3 (so 4 answers per slide). Once a user clicks on a button, that button's data value is added to the array, and the slide changes to the next one, then the user selects another option and so on. On the final slide, if the points are >3 or 3< they get shown either the success or failure divs.

Comment: @DanielN See the update to my answer. Click the buttons one by one until you click the last

Comment: @mplungjan Updated it to target last class instead of ID, but it works perfectly as expected! Thank you so much! I'm in the process of learning JS, but this stuff is still far over my head!

Answer (score 0):

`points` is not any attribute. For custom attributes use `data-*`, hence `data-points`.

Here is a basic example (based on assumptions) as to how you should go about it.

```js
let newArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];

let sum = newArr.reduce((cum,x) => {
        return cum + Number(x.getAttribute('data-points'));
},0);

console.log(sum);

if(sum > 3){
 document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'block';
 document.querySelector('.failure').style.display = 'none';
}
else{
document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('.failure').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<a data-points="0" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="1" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="2" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<a data-points="3" href="#" class="btn">Button Text</a>
<div class="success">Success</div>
<div class="failure">Failure</div>
```

1. Get all relevant `a` elements using `querySelectorAll`.
2. Compute the sum using `reduce` and `getAttribute`
3. Use `style.display` to modify the styles.